# Inconsistent wording of profiles without an "about me" section

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web

When visiting a profile without an "about me" section in a desktop browser, you'll see the text
"Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.". E.g.:

[image]

However, in the mobile browser, you'll see the text "This user has not filled their about me section yet.":

[image]

I'm guessing this inconsistency is not intentional.

Comment: ‍♂️ That’s the old mobile site. Try the new responsive site by clicking the “full site” link in the footer.